# Expectation propagation for feature selection

Tags: bayesian, feature-selection, inference

I'm using Expectation propagation algorithm (`infer.net` library) for my feature selection problem.

I generate input data and test my model. The thing is that when I use different number of data points, I get very different results.

For example, in my current setting it really works well with 50 data points. However, with more than 60 and less than 40 the result are dramatically poorer.

Can anyone explain this to me? Is it something related to Expectation Propagation? Or it is because of the way it is may be implemented in `infer.net`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe it hasn't converged.
2. Try initializing near the true answer.
3. Try a different inference algorithm.